# iphone: can i convert UIImageView animation to svg/gif file?

Tags: iphone

is there any way to convert UIImageView animation which is composed of array of images to any animated format (i.e into gif/svg) in iphone?

Answer (score 1):

For animated GIF on iphone,here is the nice example:

http://github.com/jamesu/glgif